# One foreach loop with a div and multiple li

Tags: php, html, css, foreach, html-lists

Is a structure like the following possible using a single `foreach` loop?

```
+-------------+----------+
foreach
| div/div     | ul       |
|             |   li/li  |
|             |   li/li  |
|             |   li/li  |
|             | /ul      |
endforeach
+-------------+----------+
```

With code like this, I'm getting a wrong iteration of `<ul>` and `<li>`, as you can see in [this](http://dailypeoplestime.com/) front page just below the galleries (in Front Page, Business etc.).

```
$counter = 0;
foreach( $items as $news ){
if ( $counter == 1 ) { echo '<div class="align-left">News 1</div>'; }
if ( $counter != 1 && $counter <= 4 ) {
   echo '<div class="align-right">';
    echo '<ul>';
      echo '<li>' . news . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
   echo '</div>';
}
$counter++;
} //endforeach
```

<sub>* Please note: the link I provided doesn't included the similar look I've given here in this question, but I actually need the logic.</sub>

### EDIT

I saw some misconceptions about my question.
Please note the `$items` contains news from a query, and with a `foreach` I have to place them accordingly. So I actually need the `foreach` and the design as well. If I `echo` a `<div class="align-left">News 1</div>` first,  and then call the `foreach` loop, then it'd not be possible, because I'd miss the first `news` from the `$items`.

Comment: why not just post the HTML code? doing so requires time? makes the question longer? or something else?

Comment: Do you want multiple `ul`?

Comment: @serakfalcon no. I won't. That's why the structure seems impossible with a single foreach loop. (I edited my question)

Comment: What kind of thinking is that? put the `ul` outside the foreach loop like normal people (as per Pete's answer). It's not difficult, just take a moment to think it through.

Comment: but the way you are doing your loop above will mean the first 2 items in the news array never get shown as nothing happens on 0 and you only print the title on 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this with the help of Mr. Ariful Haque.

```
$counter = 0;
$totalitems = count( $items );

foreach( $items as $news ){
if ( $counter == 1 ) { echo '<div class="align-left">News 1</div>'; }
if ( $counter != 1 && $counter <= 4 ) {
   if( $counter == 2 ) {
      echo '<div class="align-right">';
       echo '<ul>';
   } //endif
         echo '<li>' . $news . '</li>';
   if( $counter == $totalitems ) {
       echo '</ul>';
      echo '</div>';
   } //endif
}
$counter++;
} //endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your loop to the following:

```
echo '<div class="align-left">News 1</div>';
echo '<div class="align-right"><ul>'

foreach( $items as $news ){
  echo '<li>' . news . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul></div>';
```

**As per your edit** (note the first 2 items in the news loop will never be shown)

```
$counter = 0;
$total = count($items);
foreach( $items as $news ){
    if ( $counter == 1) { 
        echo '<div class="align-left">News 1</div>'; 
        if ($total > 2) {
            echo '<div class="align-right">';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
    }

    if ( $counter > 1 &&  $counter <= 4 ) {
        echo '<li>' . news . '</li>';
    }

    if ($counter == 4 || $counter == $total) {
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: It's not the solution, I'm afraid. I edited my question and clarified the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Hope you want this.

```
$counter = 0;
$item_size = count($items);
if($item_size == 1 ){
    echo '<div class="align-left">'.$item[0].'</div>'; 
}else{
   echo '<div class="align-right">';
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach( $items as $news ){
     if ( $counter == 0 ) { echo '<div class="align-left">'.$news.'</div>'; }
     if ( $counter != 0 && $counter <= 4 ) {
         echo '<li>' . $news . '</li>';
     }
     $counter++;
   } //endforeach
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '</div>';
}
```